# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Roman numeral to integer converter

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to write a program that converts a roman numeral to its corresponding integer value but I keep getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. Anytime I change something, then it outputs the wrong value. Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
char n1[] = {'C', 'X', 'I', 'I', 'I'};
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n1.length; i++) {
  char ch = n1[i];
  char next_char = n1[i + 1];

  if (ch == 'M') {
    result += 1000;
  } else if (ch == 'C') {
    if (next_char == 'M') {
      result += 900;
      i++;
    } else if (next_char == 'D') {
      result += 400;
      i++;
    } else {
      result += 100;
    }
  } else if (ch == 'D') {
    result += 500;
  } else if (ch == 'X') {
    if (next_char == 'C') {
      result += 90;
      i++;
    } else if (next_char == 'L') {
      result += 40;
      i++;
    } else {
      result += 10;
    }
  } else if (ch == 'L') {
    result += 50;
  } else if (ch == 'I') {
    if (next_char == 'X') {
      result += 9;
      i++;
    } else if (next_char == 'V') {
      result += 4;
      i++;
    } else {
      result++;
    }
  } else { // if (ch == 'V')
    result += 5;
  }
}
System.out.println("Roman Numeral: ");
for (int j = 0; j < n1.length; j++)
{
  System.out.print(n1[j]);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Number: ");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace and tell us which line in your program the stacktrace refers to. Always when asking about an exception. This information will make it much easier for us to spot what’s going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The others are correct about the cause. I think you can just set `next_char` (which according to the naming conventions should be `nextChar`) to a dummy value that doesn’t match any letter used in Roman numerals in the case that there isn’t any next char:

```
      char nextChar;
      if (i + 1 < n1.length) {
        nextChar = n1[i + 1];
      } else {
        nextChar = '\0';
      }
```

With this change your program prints:

> ```
> Roman Numeral: 
> CXIII
> Number: 
> 113
> ```

Vitor SRG is also correct that your program is lacking validation, which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop goes from `i = 0` to `i = n1.length - 1`, so the line

```
char next_char = n1[i + 1];
```

will always cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), Roman numerals are composed by up to three independent groups:

1. M, MM, MMM;
2. C, CC, CCC, CD, D, DC, DCC, DCCC, CM;
3. X, XX, XXX, XL, L, LX, LXX, LXXX, XC; and
4. I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX.

I advise you to parse them separately.

Answer (score -1):

That causes array out of bounds . You can simulate the for loop again to check this index

```
  char next_char = n1[i + 1];
```